# Guardar estado listview

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma `ListView` que trago dados do banco de dados.
Quando faço uma busca pela *search* da `ActionBar` aparece os dados filtrados, então seleciono um item da `ListView` para ver os dados da mesma. Quando eu volto pra `ListView` pelo botão *up* da `ActionBar` os itens estão como antes de eu ter feito a busca.

Como eu faço pra quando eu voltar o estado da `ListView` fique salva com a busca que eu fiz?